# How to count a foreign key and use it to sort the primary table?

Tags: sql, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables:

- Product (prod_id, prod_name, vend_id)
- Vendor (vend_id, vend_name, vend_state)

I am trying to make a query that will give me a list of the `vend_name` for every vendor that supplied only one product. `vend_id` is a foreign key in `Product`, and I would like to count how many instances of each `vend_id` are in `Product` and then list out the `vend_name` of those that only occur once. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer (because I have to).

This is what I have, but keep getting either "invalid identifier" or "group function is not allowed here"

```
select count(*), Product.vend_id, Vendor.vend_id 
from Product 
inner join Vendor on Product.vend_id = vend.vend_id 
where count(*) < 2 
group by product.vend_id, vendor.vend_name;
```

Comment: I have tried several suggestions from similar questions, but none of them are exact or work.

Comment: "I am using oracle sql developer (because i have to)" sounds so negative. Oracle is a very good DBMS and quite close to the current SQL standard, and their SQL Developer is a good tool. So why complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT vend_name
  FROM Vendor
 WHERE vend_id IN (
        SELECT vend_id
          FROM Product
         GROUP BY vend_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = 1
       )
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i had a year and a half between intro to database and advanced database so i completely forgot about nested select statement. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the Vendors that have only one Product the query is similary to:

```
select Vend_id, count(*) as Tot_Products
from Product 
group by Vend_id
having count(*) = 1
```

I advise you to lear the function `GROUP BY... HAVING`, with this you can write a condition on a column calcolata (like the result of a `MAX, MIN` and all the other functions) whitout use a nasted query like:

```
select *
from (select Vend_id, count(*) as Tot_Products
    from Product 
    group by Vend_id)
where Tot_Products = 1
```

Now you have the Id for each Vendors that have only one Product, now you can get all information of vendors with a join on Vendors, do you have something like this:

```
SELECT V.Vend_name
FROM (  select Vend_id 
        from Product 
        having count(*) = 1
        group by Vend_id )as P
inner join Vendors as V
    on p.Vend_id = V.Vend_id
```